# Category conditionals

Tags: categories

I have an entry page that lists out specific info for a product. I am using categories to sort the entries. I'm trying to figure out how to write a conditional that pulls in something specific if the entry belongs to a specific category.

Comment: So, you have a categories-field on the entry, and if a specific category is selected, you want to do something?

Comment: ya, in the entry you can select the category it's in and so I want to display something for entries that belong to a certain category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The category field returns an [ElementCriteriaModel](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), which means you can use all the methods that you'd usually use to get a specific category on it.

For instance, if the category field is named `entryCategories`, and you know the slug of the category you want to test for, you could do:

```
{% if entry.entryCategories.slug('my-category-slug').total() %}
    Do something
{% endif %}
```

Or you could use the `id`the same way.

Please note, this does not work if the entryCategory field was eager-loaded, since `entry.entryCategories` would then return an array. In that case you could just loop over the array and have a check inside for loop that checks the category you're looping over is the correct one. A bit dirty, but it does the job.

Comment: @MatthewCarleton I just updated the answer to exchange the `length` filter for the more efficient `total()` method. Instead of querying the category models it just queries for the count of rows in the database. The query itself is quicker and it also uses much less memory.